# Java build path and Opencv on ubuntu server

Tags: java, eclipse, opencv, ubuntu

I have installed Opencv 2.4.9 with Java on my server (Ubuntu Server 12.04) following this guide: http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/desktop_java/java_dev_intro.html#java-dev-intro

After, I created my java application on my PC (Eclipse, Windows 8.1), added the opencv-249.jar file in the building path and exported the .war file for the Tomcat development. When I try to execute the application I get the "java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no opencv_java249 in java.library.path" error.

How can I set the Java library path to include also the opencv/build/lib/libopencv_java249.so?